# Activityを継承していないクラスから画面遷移を行う

Tags: android, android-intent

現在非アクティビティクラスから別のアクティビティへ画面遷移をさせようとしているのですが、NullPointerExceptionが返ってきて画面遷移ができません。

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
            at appdev.test.subactivity.move(SubActivity.java:79)
            at appdev.test.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

下記のようなコードを書いているのですが、どうすれば画面遷移ができるようになるのでしょうか？宜しくお願いします。

MainActivity

```
SubActivity subactivity = new SubActivity();
subactivity.move(this);
```

SubActivity

```
public void move(Activity activity) {            
    startActivity(new Intent(activity, AnotherActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: Exception の報告では例外スタックトレースを添付してもらえると、読んだ人の理解が早いです。

Comment: 例外スタックトレースを添付いたしました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activityを継承していないクラスに、Activityインスタンスを渡せばよいような？

```
// Activityを継承していないクラス
// 多分インスタンスはActivityを継承したクラスで作られる
public class MyModel {
    private Activity mActivity;
    public MyModel(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    // このメソッド内で遷移させたい
    public void doSomething() {
        mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(mActivity, AnotherActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: このオブジェクトの生存期間が、内部で保持しているActivityよりも長い（AsyncTaskのような別スレッドで使用されるなど）場合は、WeakReferenceで持たせる必要があります。

Comment: startActivityをmActivity.startActivityに変更すれば画面遷移をすることができました！本当にありがとうございます！